# Asp.NET MVC - Difference between ViewPage and WebViewPage class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between ViewPage and WebViewPage in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 12):

A ViewPage is specific to the Web Forms View Engine, and inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.  It is used as the base class when the engine compiles .aspx files.

WebViewPage is the abstract class used (by default) as the base class for Razor-based Views when compiling .cshtml or .vbhtml files.  This default can be changed in the Views/Web.config file.